# Firebase Schedule function is running every minute instead of once a day

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Following this [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), I'm trying to run a function once a day at 7:54am Bangkok time.

My code is the following:

```
exports.scheduledCheckSellerDeliveryArea-1 = functions.pubsub.schedule('54 7 * * *')
.timeZone('Asia/Bangkok')
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('FDP!');
  return null;
});
```

Unfortunately, according to the logs it seems that the function is executed every minute

[image]

Comment: Hi @woshitom , On the code above, `exports.scheduledTestFunction`, do you intentionally type a different function name? The function name on the given screenshot was different from the given code. If not, then please post the `scheduledCheckSellerDeliveryArea-1` function instead.

Comment: yes sorry, i using 'scheduledTestFunction' in this post, but the real function name is 'scheduledCheckSellerDeliveryArea-1'

Comment: I'm not totally sure but have you tried deploying the function without that hyphen in the function name ?

Comment: Tried reproducing your issue but encountered an error: `Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.` because of the hyphen in the function name. How did you deploy the function on your `logs` screenshot? I also found a way to deploy a scheduled function that has hyphen on its name but the scheduler works fine at-least on my end.
Could you please provide us with reproducible steps so we can isolate what happened to your scheduled cloud function.